# Can one deploy non web .net core console app to Azure App Service

Tags: deployment, console-application, azure-web-app-service

I am writing a .net core console app (this is not web or API). Can I deploy this to Azure App Service? or Azure App service only supports web app?

Comment: Maybe you could try [webjob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create).

Comment: What does this Console app does? Is it on a infinite loop? If so, I agree with George that it must be deployed as a WebJob